# How to extend a bootstrap ui controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have included the bootstrap ui module in my angular project and now I want to extend for example the datepicker controller 'UibDatepickerController' in the 'ui-bootstrap-tpls.js' with further functions.

Okay, I could edit the ui bootstrap file, but that is not that what I want.

I want a modularized file (maybe an own directive) so that there are no big problems when a ui bootstrap update is incoming.

Is that possible? What is best practice?

Comment: Do you want to make changes in the html template that reside in ui-bootstrap-tpls.js?

Comment: No. I want to add further functions to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try injecting `$controller` and extending like this:

```
app.directive('myUiDirective', function ($controller) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, iElem, iAttr) {
            angular.extend(this, $controller('UibDatepickerController', {$scope: scope}));

    }
});
```

However I am not sure if you will be able to get controller from different module (in this case, from `ui.bootstrap`).

Comment: In this case I get $injector errors because it is in another module.